# How to separate paste in list of vectors

Tags: r, list, paste

Is there is a way to separate paste function in list of vectors?
An example :
I would like from this : `list(c(1),c(2,3),c(4))` which give

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

Paste all values with "%" to get :

```
[[1]]
[1] "1%"

[[2]]
[1] "2%" "3%"

[[3]]
[1] "4%"
```

Answer (score 2):

You want the `lapply()` function which takes a list and does the same thing to every element. The `lapply()` function has two principle arguments. The first is a list (or a vector). The second is a function. You can either just specify the name of the function and then pass the function's remaining arguments after that, or you can write an anonymous function. I prefer the second method since it is more reliable as what you want to do gets more complicated.

```
l1 <- list(c(1),c(2,3),c(4))
# using lapply
lapply(l1, paste, "%", sep = "")
# with an anonymous function
lapply(l1, function(x) paste(x, "%", sep=""))
```

Both of these return your desired output.

```
[[1]]
[1] "1%"

[[2]]
[1] "2%" "3%"

[[3]]
[1] "4%"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That's exactly what I need

Comment: Or a bit more concise `lapply(l1, paste0, "%")`

Answer (score 0):

We could `unlist` and apply `paste` once as it is vectorized and change it to `list` with `relist`

```
relist(paste0(unlist(l1), "%"), skeleton = l1)
#[[1]]
#[1] "1%"

#[[2]]
#[1] "2%" "3%"

#[[3]]
#[1] "4%"
```

#### data

```
l1 <- list(c(1),c(2,3),c(4))
```